# Is it possible to split an int inside an int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

My program takes the user's input of the time as a string using the format 00:00 e.g. 12:30.

I am then splitting the string where the colon is and storing the 12 and 30 in and int array. So now my array is holding the two values [12,30].

I am now trying to further split it into a new array so that for instance 12 will become [1,2]. How would I do this? Or could/should i this from the string array?

The purpose of doing this for me is so that the program can then convert the time to English. I am currently using maps. So currently my program will take the int array that hold [12,30] and pair arrayInt[0] which is 12 with the English equivilant Twelve and the same for 30.

But i want to shorten my program so when the minute is 35, I wont have to make a `map.put(35, "Thirty Five")` but be able to split the 35 into 3,5 and reuse my `map.put(30, "Thirty")` and `map.put(5, "Five")` instead of having 60 lines of map.put for the minutes.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Why not convert the whole string to a time value instead?

Comment: unless you need to deal with those individual `1`, `2` directly, you'd be better off converting to an internal time value. then you can use the built-in formatting options to slice/dice any kind of time string you want.

Comment: sounds like you want `String.toCharArray`. I don't know if it's really what you _want_, but it's what you're asking for.

Comment: I agree with @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for what purpose you are doing this?

Comment: @MarcB Correct. I need have to deal with each character individually later in the program. It's so that I can later convert them to "English." like 01:35 would be One Thirty Five.

Comment: ok. but would you then need to take that `0`, `1` and conver it back to a `01` later? if you're going to be doing conversions in both directions, then definitely store as an internal/native time value, and extract the individual values as needed later.

Comment: If you want to use a translation map, you just have to insert 1-19, 20, 30, 40, 50 by hand. You can use loops to insert the rest because they are just combinations of numbers that you already inserted.  Still tedious, but more like 30 lines instead of 60.

Comment: @mstbaum if you map 10 to "-teen", you could actually have just 1-15 be manual. Sixteen, seventeen, eighteen and nineteen all follow the standard pattern.

Comment: @yshavit you could, but it wouldn't really save you any coding.  And you wouldn't want to map 10 to teen because you'll never use it like that again.  Plus the teens still follow a different pattern than twenty-one, thirty-two, etc.